# htaccess rewrite clean url for multiple parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my `.htaccess` code for clean url rewriting.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[a-zA-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?bank=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2%3%4? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?bank=$1$2$3$4 [L,QSA]
```

This code works fine for single parameter in `url`. For example it `rewrites`

`http://example.com/example-path/` to
`http://example.com/index.php?bank=example-path/`

But when I tried to pass multiple parameters in `url`, all I got are `errors`.

I need a url like
`http://example.com/example-path` instead of `http://example.com/index.php?bank=example-path`

How can I alter My code to pass multiple urls.

Comment: Use temporary 302 redirects for development rather than permanent 301 redirects. A 301 redirect is good for when a website permanently moves, such as changing domain names. But when it comes to URL rewriting, you'll find even in production one is constantly moving things around, and 301 redirects will get you into trouble due to browser caching. Try switching to 302 redirects, and continue testing in a different browser which doesn't have the redirect cached, or clear your browser cache from the 301 redirect.

Answer (score 2):

Your redirect logic can be greatly simplified to just:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#If a request does not match an existing directory
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#And does not match an existing file
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#then rewrite all requests to index.php
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?bank=$1 [L,QSA]
```